# Passing an i18n message as a parameter to a Grails template

Tags: grails, internationalization, gsp

I have a Grails template file that i use in multiple .gsp views, being called like this:

```
<g:render template="/template/mail/notification/notification_email" model="[
    title: 'A string',
    text: 'Another string',
]"/>
```

However, I'd like to move `A string` and `Another string` to a messages.properties file.

How can I set the template model values to the proper values, given that I cannot use `<g:message>` inside the `<g:render>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
<g:render template="/template/mail/notification/notification_email" model="[
    title: g.message( code: 'your.title' ),
    text: g.message( code: 'your.text' ),
]"/>
```